# How to automatically mock a class in a class with phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a class structure like this:

```
class A {
    public someFunction() {
        $objectB = new B();
        $result = $objectB->getResult();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I am writing the unit test for `someFunction()` that belongs to class `A`. However, it depends on class `B`. I can mock `someFunction()` but how can I resolve the dependency on class B? I want to mock class `B` automatically.

Comment: What is your understanding of mocking? If you're going to test `someFunction`, why would you mock it? You would normally mock the dependencies of your test subject -- not your test subject itself.

Comment: I made a mistake, i wanted to mock object class A and test someFunction.It depends class B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dependency injection: either provide a method to set the B object, or pass the b object optionally to `someFunction()`.

### Original code

```
class A {
    public function someFunction() {
        $objectB = new B();
        $result = $objectB->getResult();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

### Optional parameter

```
class A {
    public function someFunction($objectB = null) {
        if ($objectB == null) { $objectB = new B(); }
        $result = $objectB->getResult();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

### Setter method

```
class A {
    protected $b;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new B();
    }

    public function setB($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        $result = $this->b->getResult();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add: The goal for new testable classes should usually be to get rid of the `if $var == null  $var new Object(); ` line all together and you pass it in from the outside. Just having that "optional just for testing" also can work but usually isn't the end goal or all that pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility for dependency injection is to refactor to an "init" method, i.e.:

```
class A
{
    function setB ( B $b = null )
    {
        $this->b = ( !is_null($b) ? $b
            $this->initB()
        );
    }

    function initB ( )
    {
       return new B();
    }

    function someMethod ( )
    {
        return $this->b->getResult();
    }
}
```

With this implementation, subclasses of "A" can override "initB" to change the dependency and a mock of A generated with "PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::getMock()" can define a canned return value for the method without relying on the functionality of the setter (or you can omit the setter).